# Code works in latex but not in miktex-xetex

Tags: xetex, pstricks

I am trying to render a tex diagram. It works in one program but not the other. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,graphicx}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
  \psset{linecolor=gray,unit=0.75bp}
    \begin{pspicture}(-352,-352)(352,352)
    \psrotate(0,0){345}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-280){\color{gray}{\large\itshape{H}}}}
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psarc[]{-}(0,0){256}{0}{360}
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt}
%    \psrotate(0,0){  0}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{0}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){ 30}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{30}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){ 60}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{60}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){ 90}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{90}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){120}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{120}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){150}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{150}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){180}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{180}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){210}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{210}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){240}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{240}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){270}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{270}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){300}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{300}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){330}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{330}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){  0}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){ 30}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){ 60}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){ 90}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){120}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){150}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){180}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){210}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){240}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){270}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){300}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){330}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the Windows batch file that works:

```
latex %1.tex
dvips -E %1.dvi
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None %1.ps
convert -density 600 %1.pdf -quality 90 %1.png
%1.png
```

Here is the Windows batch file that does not output the diagram correctly:

```
miktex-xetex.exe -synctex=1 -undump=xelatex %1.tex
convert -density 600 %1.pdf -quality 90 %1.png
```

Can the code be fixed? Why doesn't it work? Thanks.

Comment: When you say "works in one program" are you referring to the actual code you've posted? The code is not running in my machine. The error I'm getting is `! Undefined control sequence.`. Also, what do you mean by "It works in one program but not the other"? Are you having problem with the actual code or the terminal commands?

Comment: pstricks for XeTeX is a subset of the full one
for dvips. I confirmed that XeTeX can create a
pdf for your example, but the result is not an
expected one.

Comment: The code is supposed to create a ring with angle markers on it. The first batch file is able to produce the desired figure. The second batch file is not. The result of running the second batch file is that the angle marker labels are all overlapping instead of spread out around the ring at even intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\psset{linecolor=gray,unit=0.75bp}

\begin{pspicture}(-352,-352)(352,352)
\color{gray}%
\pscircle[linewidth=2pt](0,0){256}
\uput{10}[255]{-15}(256;255){\textcolor{gray}{\large\textit{H}}}%
\multido{\iA=30+30,\iB=120+30,\iC=210+30}{11}{\uput{10}[\iB]{\iC}(256;\iB){\iA}}%
\multido{\iA=0+30}{12}{\psline[linewidth=0.5pt](260;\iA)(250;\iA)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]