# Xelatex output error

Tags: pstricks, winedt

I'm trying to render the following drawing in WinEdt using Xelatex:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,graphicx}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
  \psset{linecolor=gray,unit=0.75bp}
    \begin{pspicture}(-352,-352)(352,352)
    \psrotate(0,0){345}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-280){\color{gray}{\large\itshape{H}}}}
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psarc[]{-}(0,0){256}{0}{360}
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt}
%    \psrotate(0,0){  0}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{0}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){ -30}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{30}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){ -60}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{60}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){ -90}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{90}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){-120}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{120}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){-150}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{150}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){-180}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{180}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){-210}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{210}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){-240}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{240}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){-270}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{270}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){-300}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{300}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){-330}{\rput[B]{0}(0,-276){{\color{gray}{330}}}}
    \psrotate(0,0){  -0}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){ -30}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){ -60}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){ -90}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){-120}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){-150}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){-180}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){-210}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){-240}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){-270}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){-300}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
    \psrotate(0,0){-330}{\psline(0,252)(0,260)}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

However, all the text labels are in the bottom overlapping. There should also be ticks around the perimeter of the circle. Here is the log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.2.6)  6 FEB 2019 20:23
entering extended mode
**./cie_axis_H360_cyl_sans_360_cw.tex
(cie_axis_H360_cyl_sans_360_cw.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.
cls
Document Class: standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files stand
alone
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count80
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count81
\c@sapage=\count82

(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.
cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2015/07/15 v1.2 Default configuration file for 'standalone
' class
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count83
\c@section=\count84
\c@subsection=\count85
\c@subsubsection=\count86
\c@paragraph=\count87
\c@subparagraph=\count88
\c@figure=\count89
\c@table=\count90
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pstricks\pstricks.sty"
Package: pstricks 2018/12/21 v0.69 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, 
and LuaTeX
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty"
Package: shellesc 2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 69.
)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 225.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def"
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex"
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex"
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count91
\pstFP@xia=\count92
\pstFP@xib=\count93
\pstFP@xfa=\count94
\pstFP@xfb=\count95
\pstFP@rega=\count96
\pstFP@regb=\count97
\pstFP@regs=\count98
\pstFP@times=\count99
)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfuti
l-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfuti
l-common-lists.tex))
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkey
s.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkey
sfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor
.code.tex
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.cod
e.tex
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc
.code.tex
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil
.code.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@xa=\dimen106
\pgf@xb=\dimen107
\pgf@xc=\dimen108
\pgf@y=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@yb=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\c@pgf@counta=\count100
\c@pgf@countb=\count101
\c@pgf@countc=\count102
\c@pgf@countd=\count103
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count104
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count105
)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathpars
er.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count106
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks22
)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunc
tions.code.tex
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunc
tions.basic.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunc
tions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunc
tions.random.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunc
tions.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunc
tions.base.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunc
tions.round.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunc
tions.misc.code.tex)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunc
tions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloa
t.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count107
))
\pgffor@iter=\dimen114
\pgffor@skip=\dimen115
\pgffor@stack=\toks23
\pgffor@toks=\toks24
)
\psLoopIndex=\count108

`PSTricks' v2.92  <2018/12/27> (tvz,hv)
\pst@dima=\dimen116
\pst@dimb=\dimen117
\pst@dimc=\dimen118
\pst@dimd=\dimen119
\pst@dimg=\dimen120
\pst@dimh=\dimen121
\pst@dimm=\dimen122
\pst@dimn=\dimen123
\pst@dimo=\dimen124
\pst@dimp=\dimen125
\pst@hbox=\box28
\pst@ibox=\box29
\pst@boxg=\box30
\pst@cnta=\count109
\pst@cntb=\count110
\pst@cntc=\count111
\pst@cntd=\count112
\pst@cntg=\count113
\pst@cnth=\count114
\pst@cntm=\count115
\pst@cntn=\count116
\pst@cnto=\count117
\pst@cntp=\count118
\@zero=\count119
\pst@toks=\toks25

(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks\pstri
cks.con ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\xdvipdfmx.cfg"))
\psunit=\dimen126
\psxunit=\dimen127
\psyunit=\dimen128
\pst@C@@rType=\count120
\pslinewidth=\dimen129
\psk@startLW=\dimen130
\psk@endLW=\dimen131
\pst@customdefs=\toks26
\pslinearc=\dimen132
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen133
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen134
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen135
\everypsbox=\toks27
\psframesep=\dimen136
\pslabelsep=\dimen137
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen138
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen139
\pst@shift=\dimen140

(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks\pstri
cks.con ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\xdvipdfmx.cfg"
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
)))
File: pstricks.tex 2018/12/27 v2.92 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex")
File: pst-fp.tex 2018/12/27 v2.92 `PST-fp' (hv)

>>> Loading XeTeX special macros
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks-xetex.def"))
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/preview\preview.sty
Package: preview 2010/02/14 11.89 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)

(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/preview\prtightpage.de
f
\PreviewBorder=\dimen141
)
\pr@snippet=\count121
\pr@box=\box31
\pr@output=\toks28
))
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/pst-plot\pst-plot.sty
Package: pst-plot 2011/06/05 v1.00 LaTeX wrapper for `pst-plot' (HV)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\pst-xkey.sty"
Package: pst-xkey 2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/multido\multido.sty
Package: multido 2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)


(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/multido\multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>
\multido@count=\count122
\multidocount=\count123
\multido@stuff=\toks29
)
File: multido.tex 2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
)
Package: pst-plot 2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)

(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-plot\pst-plot.te
x
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-tools\pst-tools.
tex `PST-tools' v0.05, 2014/05/12 (hv))
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pstricks-add\pstrick
s-add.tex
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-node\pst-node.te
x  v1.36, 2016/04/24
\psrow=\count124
\pscol=\count125
\psmatrixcnt=\count126
\psrowsep=\skip43
\pscolsep=\skip44
\pst@args=\count127
\num@pts=\count128
\pst@argcnt=\count129
)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-arrow\pst-arrow.
tex `pst-arrow' v0.01, 2016/09/01 (dr,hv)
\pshooklength=\dimen142
\pshookwidth=\dimen143
)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-3d\pst-3d.tex
`PST-3d' v1.11, 2010/02/14 (tvz))
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-math\pst-math.te
x `pst-math' v0.63 , (CJ,hv)) `pstricks-add' v3.82, 2016/09/01 (dr,hv)
\psparallelogramsep=\dimen144
\pst@cntC=\count130
\chart@ColorIndex=\dimen145
\chart@ColorStep=\dimen146
\pst@chartHeight=\dimen147
\pst@chartStackDepth=\dimen148
\pst@chartStackWidth=\dimen149
\chart@Toggle=\count131
\psVectorCtr=\count132
)
 v1.75, 2016/05/18 (tvz,hv)
\pstRadUnit=\dimen150
\pstRadUnitInv=\dimen151
\pst@linecnt=\count133
\RCD@file=\read1
\psxlabelsep=\dimen152
\psylabelsep=\dimen153
\psk@subticksize=\dimen154
\pst@xticksizeA=\dimen155
\pst@xticksizeB=\dimen156
\pst@xticksizeC=\dimen157
\pst@yticksizeA=\dimen158
\pst@yticksizeB=\dimen159
\pst@yticksizeC=\dimen160
\@digitcounter=\count134
\psk@llx=\dimen161
\psk@lly=\dimen162
\psk@urx=\dimen163
\psk@ury=\dimen164
\pst@xunit=\dimen165
\pst@yunit=\dimen166
)
File: pst-plot.tex 2016/05/18 1.75 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen167
\Gin@req@width=\dimen168
)
(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/tex-gyre\tgheros.sty
Package: tgheros 2009/09/27 v1.2 TeX Gyre Heros as default sans serif family

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 105.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\t1lmr.fd"
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
(cie_axis_H360_cyl_sans_360_cw.aux)
\openout1 = `cie_axis_H360_cyl_sans_360_cw.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+qhv on input line 6.

(C:\Users\Mike-7PRO\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/tex-gyre\t1qhv.fd
File: t1qhv.fd 2009/09/25 v1.2 font definition file for T1/qhv
)
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1

Overfull \hbox (184.97656pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 37--37
[][] 
 []

Preview: Tightpage 0 0 0 0
[1] (cie_axis_H360_cyl_sans_360_cw.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10561 strings out of 427748
 183271 string characters out of 3150982
 319042 words of memory out of 3000000
 14476 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 15858 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 43i,4n,56p,663b,275s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on cie_axis_H360_cyl_sans_360_cw.pdf (1 page).
```

The drawing worked properly for me in the past using a different workflow and library IIRC. Have I configured Xeletex or WinEdt improperly? Thanks.

Comment: I confirm the issue on my TeXLive 2018 distribution on MacOS. That is, the output with `xelatex` is incorrect whereas compiling this with `latex`, converting the `dvi` to `ps` and then to `pdf` gives the correct result. (I had several several issues with `xelatex` in the past. Yet I have not checked whether or not the old ones got resolved.)

Comment: did you consider the answer you accepted before https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/360715/170109

Comment: Oh wow, I forgot about that. That answer works correctly here too. I guess it's a duplicate.

Comment: @marmot it was not an answer just a comment that OP had asked the same question and may have forgotten but can edit question to request new answers ?

Comment: @KJOYes, I agree.